# JavaScript/JQuery: Add Numbers from Fields accounting for Undefined (with 0)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 input fields and a 3rd one called "Total". Whenever any one of the two changes, the total has to be updated with the sum.

This calculation has to take into account empty/undefined values. Is there a quick way to do it? I am using Number(x). Will it take care of unentered values? In the case of unentered, 0 should be assumed.

```
   $('#field1').on("change", function() {
        updateTotalCosts();
    });
   $('#field2').on("change", function() {
        updateTotalCosts();
    });           
   function updateTotalCosts() {
       var f1 = $('#field1').val();
       var f2 = $('#field2').val();
       $('#total').val( Number(f1) + Number(f2) );
```

Comment: Are they floating point numbers or integer? There is a very quick trick for integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note `change` event fires after the `input` loses focus. You may want to use `input` event instead.

To convert the string to numbers, you can use the unary operator `+` instead of `Number`.

To default to `0` when some expression is falsy, you can use `expr || 0`.

```js
var field1 = document.getElementById('field1'),
    field2 = document.getElementById('field2'),
    total = document.getElementById('total');
field1.oninput = field2.oninput = function updateTotalCosts() {
  total.value = (+field1.value || 0) + (+field2.value || 0);
};
```

```html
<input id="field1" />
+ <input id="field2" />
= <input id="total" />
```

Or, using jQuery,

```js
var $field1 = $('#field1'),
    $field2 = $('#field2'),
    $total = $('#total');
$field1.add($field2).on('input change', function updateTotalCosts() {
  $total.val((+$field1.val() || 0) + (+$field2.val() || 0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field1" />
+ <input id="field2" />
= <input id="total" />
```

Comment: It's a jQuery question. Why mess it up with raw javascript? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I have added a snippet using jQuery. But it's almost the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
var f1 = +$('#field1').val() || 0;
```

The unary `+` operator coerces result to a number (or tries to), if the result is falsy, replace with 0.

Answer (score 1):

If they are integer values, use `~~` to convert strings (`undefined` converts to 0) to integers.

```
var one;
var two = "2";
var total = ~~one + ~~two;
alert(total);            // Alerts 2
```

This works for positive and negative integers:
http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/heuoLu3d/
http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/heuoLu3d/1/

For floats use @Jared Smith's answer

Comment: Note this does not work with integers equal or greater than 2^31 in absolute value.

Comment: @Oriol: If they *were* working with integers (turned out to be floats anyway), that is a *very* big number :)